# Banach Space Adjoint of Bounded Operator on $(\ell_1)^*$ acting on $\ell_\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

My textbook has this example:

Let $T$ be the operator on $\ell_1$ with $T(a_1,a_2,..) = (a_2,a_3,..)$.

If $T'$ denotes the Banach space adjoint of $T$, $T'$ acts on $\ell_\infty$ (isometric to the $(\ell_1)^*$) by $T'(x_1,x_2..) = (0,x_1,x_2,..)$.

Can you help me see the details of how to derive this?

The isometry I know of between $(\ell_1)^*$ and $\ell_\infty$ is:

$\phi: \ell_\infty \to (\ell_1)^*$;

$\phi(x) = \phi_x$ s.t $\phi_x(a_1,a_2,..) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_ia_i$, but I can't see how to use this to formalise that statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of the adjoint of a continuous linear $S \colon X \to Y$ is

$$S'(\lambda) = (\lambda \circ S) \colon x \mapsto \lambda(Sx)$$

for $\lambda \in Y^{\ast}$. Here we have $X = Y = \ell_1$, and we write the linear functional $\lambda$ as $\phi(x)$ for some $x\in \ell_{\infty}$, so we get

$$T'\bigl(\phi(x)\bigr) \colon a \mapsto \phi(x)\bigl(T(a)\bigr) = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} x_i (T(a))_i = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} x_ia_{i+1} = \sum_{i = 2}^{\infty} x_{i-1} a_i.$$

We can write the last as

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} y_i a_i = \phi(y)(a)$$

for $y \in \ell_{\infty}$ with $y_1 = 0$ and $y_i = x_{i-1}$ for $i \geqslant 2$.